# Use of 还 in reference to "on top of that, also"

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-requests, sentence-structure

I'm just wondering whether I'm allowed to use 还 to mean, "on top of that, also". Here's the context:

在经济方面，新思维能提高生产力,而且还能产生创新和发明。As in, "in the economic sense, new ideas can increase productivity, and (on top of that) can also produce new innovations and inventions.

Is this okay??

Thanks very much in advance to whoever can help with this one!

Comment: Yes, it is OK. You can also use 更.

Comment: Thanks again! Also is the rest of my sentence ok? Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, I think it's OK. 思维 can be replaced by 想法 or 主意 (not 注意). However, "new" does not mean "good". Thus, you may use 好(的).

Comment: Right. So you're saying: 在经济方面，好的想法能提高生产力，而且还能产生创新和发明 is better? Btw you're language skills (both chinese and english) are very impressive.

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: also note 再加上, 100 examples at jukuu, "on top of that": 100 samples: 1.  On top of that, add climate change and the spectre of globle warming.
 **除此之外，还要加上**  气候变化和全球变暖带来的灾难。除此以外, 此外

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [还 ( hái ㄏㄞˊ )](http://www.zdic.net/z/25/xs/8FD8.htm)
>
> (7) 更加 [even more]。
>   (9) 不但(不仅,不光)…还… [not only ...... but also]。

In the economic sense, good ideas can increase productivity, and can also produce new innovations and inventions.
在经济方面，好的想法能提高生产力，而且还能产生创新和发明。

Similar words of 还能:

还可以
好的想法可以提高生产力，(而且)还可以产生创新和发明。

也可以、也能
好的想法可以提高生产力，(而且)也可以产生创新和发明。

更可以、更能
好的想法可以提高生产力，(而且)更可以产生创新和发明。

不但(不仅、不光、不只)能……，还能(也能、更能)……
好的想法不但能提高生产力，还能产生创新和发明。